# Terraform: GCP set static IPv6 for instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to deploy in GCP a vm instance with external static ipv4 and ipv6 (Regional) using Terraform.

I can create VPC, subnet and instance with ipv6 support and external static ipv4, but I can't set it for ipv6.
This is my code:

```
# Create VPC WITH IPV6 
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name                    = "${var.project_name}-${var.deploy_env[var.workspace]}-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  routing_mode            = "REGIONAL"
  mtu                     = 1460
}
# create subnetwork with ipv6 support
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "vpc_subnetwork" {
  name              = "${var.project_name}-${var.deploy_env[var.workspace]}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range     = "10.156.0.0/20"
  region            = var.region
  stack_type        = "IPV4_IPV6"
  ipv6_access_type  = "EXTERNAL"
  network           = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
}
# create Instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
  name = "${var.project_name}-${var.deploy_env[var.workspace]}-monitoring"
  machine_type = "g1-small"
  zone = "${var.zone}"
  tags = ["http-server", "https-server"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "image"
    }
    device_name = "${var.project_name}-${var.deploy_env[var.workspace]}-monitoring"
    auto_delete = true
    mode        = "READ_WRITE"
  }

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = true
    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
    provisioning_model  = "STANDARD"
  }

  network_interface {
    network     = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
    subnetwork  = google_compute_subnetwork.vpc_subnetwork.id
    stack_type  = "IPV4_IPV6"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral public IP
      nat_ip        = google_compute_address.external_ipv4_vip1.address
      network_tier  = "PREMIUM"
    }
    ipv6_access_config {
      network_tier  = "PREMIUM"
    }
  }
}
# IPV4
resource "google_compute_address" "external_ipv4_vip1" {
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  name         = "${var.project_name}-${var.deploy_env[var.workspace]}-ipv4-vip1"
  network_tier = "PREMIUM"
  region       = var.region
}
# IPV6
```

How can set a static IPV6 IP in my region, and assign to my istance?
Using `google_compute_address` I can set only ipv4 external IP.
I can create manually from the GUI an external IPV6 in my region and assign to my istances, but I need to run this by terraform.

Comment: Can you refer to this [blog](https://mihaibojin.medium.com/deploy-and-configure-google-compute-engine-vms-with-terraform-f6b708b226c1) by Mihai Bojin seems to be you need to use something like  `network = google_compute_network.ipv6net.id` or `nat_ip6    = google_compute_address.ipv6.address # For IPv6`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but it doens't work.
```nat_ip6``` doesn't exist in ```ipv6_access_config```.